# Is it possible to simplify an event that does the same thing for every panel?

Tags: c#, winforms

I wanted to make certain panels have their own custom border color, and the only way to accomplish this (as far as I know) is to manually subscribe every individual panel to a paint event that changes the color, and call it that way.

Eventually, half the code is going to look like this, which isn't very friendly and is most likely a bad code practice.

```csharp
        private void panel1_Paint_1(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics, panel1.ClientRectangle, Color.FromArgb(255, 11, 94, 176), ButtonBorderStyle.Solid);
        }

        private void panel2_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics, panel2.ClientRectangle, Color.FromArgb(255, 11, 94, 176), ButtonBorderStyle.Solid);
        }

        private void panel3_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics, panel3.ClientRectangle, Color.FromArgb(255, 11, 94, 176), ButtonBorderStyle.Solid);
        }

 // and so on... (repeated 6 times for each of the 6 panels)
```

Is there a way to make this more optimized and less repetitive?

Answer (score 2):

## Yes, it can be optimized and shortened.

Because of the fact all of the panels are being subscribed to the same Paint event, it is possible to create a custom paint event that applies to every panel (you choose to) subscribe it to.

```csharp
  private void HomePanels_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
  {
      Panel panel = (Panel)sender;
      ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics, panel.ClientRectangle, Color.FromArgb(255, 11, 94, 176), ButtonBorderStyle.Solid);
  }
```

With this, it's now possible to subscribe all the panels to the same event without having to make several new ones. This shortens the code by a lot, and seems like a better optimized way to pull this off.

```csharp
  private void SubscribePanelsToPaintEvent()
  {
      panel1.Paint += HomePanels_Paint;
      panel2.Paint += HomePanels_Paint;
      panel3.Paint += HomePanels_Paint;
      panel4.Paint += HomePanels_Paint;
      panel5.Paint += HomePanels_Paint;
      panel6.Paint += HomePanels_Paint;
  }
```

The most important step is to call the subscription function when the form loads or is initialized.  (I put it below InitializeComponent() )

```csharp
     SubscribePanelsToCommonPaintEvent();
```

There may be an even better way to optimize this, but it's much better than the practice that was shown earlier.